# Clear Image in the Imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, drawable

I went through many threads but i could not get the answer yet .

I am setting an image to the imageView programmatically as

```
imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.Drawable.image);
```

if i set image as the above , will the image get cleared if i give

```
imageview.setImageDrawable(null);
```

what does `imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(null)` meant ?

What is the difference between

```
imageview.setImageDrawable(null);
```

and

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(null);
```

and

```
imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`setBackgroundDrawable()` is deprecated. You should use `setBackground` instead.

Basically the difference is the parameter. In `setImageBitmap()` you have to pass a Bitmap object. In `setImageDrawable()` you have to pass a `Drawable` object. setBackground just change the background of the imageview.

The imageview can have a background and a image content. If you are defining the background and want to clear the imageview, you should use `setBackground(null)`.

Comment: setBackgroundResource(0) is the best option. from the documentation. setBackground Require ApI 16 or greater.. see here    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29

Comment: [setBackground(null)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) and [setImageDrawable(null)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) are the documented way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried with :

```
imageview.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: How do I get this in xml?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Here,

```
imageview.setImageDrawable(null);
```

will clear the the background of an `ImageView`,

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(null);
```

will clear the ImageBitmap from an `ImageView`, and

```
imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.Drawable.image);
```

will set the Images for your path e.g your path (`R.Drawable.image`)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to inflate & clear ImageView

1. If you have inflated using,

   **imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.xyz));**

   then clear using,

   **imageView.setImageDrawable(null);**
2. If you have inflated using,

   **imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xyz);**

   then clear using,

   **imageView.setBackground(null);**

So basically if you inflate ImageDrawable, then you remove ImageDrawable.
 If you inflate backgroung, then you remove background. Similarly for ImageBitmap.

Answer (score 0):

`setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)` : Sets a `Bitmap` as the content of this
 `ImageView`

`setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)`: Sets a drawable as the
 content of this `ImageView`

Comment: i am asking the difference of setting it to null . i want to clear the image .